# Как в ZeroBlock Tilda, вставить блоки с информацией и картинками, из каталога товаров?

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн, tilda

У меня задание, сделать так что бы был огромный блок. А в нём разные пиццы. И всё это можно было менять из каталога товаров. Например, в каталоге товаров у меня 10 пицц, значит в блоке для покупки будут отображаться 10 пицц. Заказчик меняет на 5 пицц, и в блоке появляется 5пицц. Как это зделать?